# MVC ASP.NET Logs shows - The controller for path '/scripts/setup.php' was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've deployed mvc asp.net application in azure and enabled diagnostics. While looking at WADLogsTable I find this:

*The controller for path '/scripts/setup.php' was not found..... 
The controller for path '/myadmin/scripts/setup.php' was not found ......
The controller for path '/db/scripts/setup.php' was not found.......*

Could anyone guide me whether this is an issue with Azure or someone trying to hack? Should I be logging this errors, if not how do I ignore. I log the unhandled exception on Application_error of Global.asax page.

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of worms out there trying every ip and web address they can get their hands on, looking for security vulnerabilities.  They try lots of different variations.  This is nothing to worry about if you're not using php, and not using any of the flawed products.  It just happens.

Comment: @flybyte - i'm not that familiair with azure, so I don't know.. but i would imagine not, since the whole point of logs is to know what's happening.  Suppose you were under a DDoS attack using a url you weren't logging, you would have no idea of what was happening.